# Time in Nanosecond accuracy on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, time

Linux is able to measure its time in nanosecond accuracy such as **Timespec** . So ,is it able to get a nanosecond accuracy on Windows ?

Comment: The accuracy depends on the hardware. What is wrong with just millisecond accuracy?

Comment: I am porting Linux application which uses nanosecond instead of millisec to Windows platform. hmm...

Comment: You should use a portable framework library like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)

Comment: Short of QPC, if I recall correctly 100ns is the best resolution that Windows offers anywhere. Of course resolution does not necessarily mean accurracy (nor under Windows nor under Linux). Quite possibly the last 3-4 digits will be zero.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the closest is a Tick

- 1 second = 10 million ticks
- 1 second = 1 billion nanoseconds

```
PS > Measure-Command {sleep 2}
Ticks             : 19997740
TotalSeconds      : 1.999774
TotalMilliseconds : 1999.774
```